# Verwendung von "zum" vs. "zu dem"

Tags: grammar, preposition, article, contractions, definite-article

Gibt es noch mehr Regeln als die folgenden, wann nur die Kontraktion und wann nur die expandierte Form verwendet werden kann?

**1.** Wenn auf das "dem" eine Satzgruppe folgt, kann nicht kontrahiert werden:
Wir halten sicher nicht zu dem, der dort gerade die Regeln verletzt hat.

Nachdem bernd_k mein Beispiel nicht mag, füge ich hier noch Googlefundstücke hinzu:

Vom gefährlichsten Mann der Welt zu dem, der sich am besten verstecken kann (diepresse.com, Artikel über Bin Laden)

Alles kommt zu dem, der warten kann (Münchener Freiheit, Liedtext)

...fielen die vierundzwanzig Ältesten nieder vor dem, der auf dem Stuhl saß  (Lutherbibel, Offenbarung Kapitel 4)

Ein anderes etwas anderes Beispiel aus einem Blog:
"Die Niedertracht, zu der die DDR fähig war"

**2.** In manchen Situation ist beides möglich, hat aber nach meinen Empfinden verschiedene Bedeutung:
Wir gehen zur Schule. Wir gehen zu der Schule.

Comment: Gute Vorschläge für sinnvolle Tags zu dieser Frage sind sehr erwünscht. Ich halte "usage" für nicht besonders nützlich, aber etwas besseres ist mir auch nicht eingefallen.

Comment: 1. Richtig `Wir helfen dem nicht, der unsportlich spielt.` Ich finde keine akzeptable Wendung mit zu in diesem Fall.

Comment: @bernd_k: Es geht mir hier um "zu jemandem helfen" als Fan im Stadion.

Comment: Als allgemeine Aussage erfordert das den Plural `Wir halten nicht zu denen, die unsportlich spielen.` dann wirkt es flüssig oder im Singular `Wir halten nicht zu demjenigen, der unsportlich spielt.` `dem` würde sich auf Sachen und nicht auf Personen beziehen und hat mich deshalb verwirrt.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank für die Tags.

Im übrigen habe ich den Satz weiter editiert. Diese Konstruktion kommt schon vor, sie erfordert nur mehr Kontext, als in einem kleinen Beispielsatz gegeben.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine weitere Regel: Bei festen Redewendungen wie

> **Zum Teufel** mit diesen neumodischen Geräten!

oder

> **Zum Kuckuck!** *(ein Kraftausdruck*)

oder

> Ich habe Rom heuer **zum ersten Mal** besucht.
>   **Zum wiederholten Male** brachen Diebe ins Schloss ein.

darf nicht "zu dem" stehen.

Die Verwendung des Artikels liegt bei vielen Funktionsverbgefügen fest. Funktionsverben sind Verben, die das Prädikat zusammen mit einem Nomen bilden. Die Verwendung der verschmolzenen Formen  `Präposition` + `Artikel` ist bei festen Wendungen – wenn möglich – obligatorisch, zum Beispiel:

> **zum** Ausdruck bringen

Wenn die feste Redewendung **keinen Artikel vorsieht**, darf er auch nicht mit der Präposition *zu* verschmolzen werden:

> **zu** Ende bringen (nicht: *zu dem Ende bringen*)

Answer (score 3):

Entscheidend ist nur, ob "dem" Artikel oder Pronomen (egal welcher Art) ist:
Den Artikel verschmilzt man dann immer, sofern vorhanden, jedwede Pronomen nie.
Dementsprechend würde ich das Tag [pronouns] ergänzen.

Zu 1.

> Der ist unzuverlässig, wir halten nicht zu dem.

Hier darf man genauso wenig verschmelzen, wie im Beispiel 1 der Frage.

Zu 2.
Will man hier die Semantik der Variante ohne Verschmelzen, so sollte man vielleicht besser

> "zu dieser Schule"

verwenden.
In

> "zu der Schule"

wäre m.E. "der" dann ebenso ein attributiv gebrauchtes Demonstrativpronomen und kein Artikel.

Answer (score 2):

Ohne jetzt wirklich sicher zu sein, würde ich behaupten, dass eine Kontraktion dann nicht durchgeführt werden kann, wenn das „dem“ in „zu dem“ alleiniges Objekt des Satzes ist. Oder anders gesagt, wenn das „dem“ lediglich eine reflektierte Version des Artikels ist, dann kann die Kontraktion durchgeführt werden.

Der „Regel“ von splattne, dass bei solchen Redewendungen kein „zu dem“ stehen darf, würde ich nicht direkt zustimmen. Grammatikalisch würde es meistens schon funktionieren; es ist eben nur so, dass die Redewendungen nur dann als Redewendungen verstanden werden, wenn sie zum größten Teil beibehalten werden.